# Not able to run cell on a jupyterlab notebook Google cloud ai platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-lab, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I am running 2 instances under Google AI Platform, which basically launches 2 VM instances to run jupyter lab. I have been happily making notebooks on both VMs. I shutdown both VMs for the day...

What's strange is that next morning, notebook from one VM will launch but when I run any cell containing simple things like "import pandas", it never return result and hang the whole thing (with a * where the cell # would have generated). I create a whole new notebook and just do a simple print("hello"). it also never returns. I restarted the instance a few times and still doesn't work. What I noticed is the "dot" on the top right corner is filled black. I think it should be white when the kernel is restarted. So there could be a problem with the kernel.

Any ideas what could go wrong? I don't even know where to debug this. The strange thing is the other VM still worked. I don't want to do anything drastic like re-creating a new VM, since I like to be able to fix this for a known cause.

Anyone out there experienced same thing?

Comment: Update: If i switch to "Python 2", that seems to work. So this means there's a problem with Python 3 Kernel. Wonder how could this be?

Comment: I ended up creating a new instance (VM), and ran the same notebook (by download/re-upload) with python3 kernel, and it works. So I suspect some python related setup must have been messed up in the VM that has problem.

Comment: I am having similar troubles that only seem to clear up if the VM is stopped and then restarted again. Which is ridiculous given the commands are doing machine learning which takes a while. Refreshing doesn't help. Local Jupyter does not do this, Google.

Comment: Having a similar issue, is there any fix to this yet? AI-platform is lacking support to these known issues!

Answer (score 0):

In case you didn't attempt this, I would try refreshing the notebook window after restarting the machine.

Comment: Thought I tried that but didnt work. If you read the comment above, I think python3 kernel and setup is the culprit. I didnt have chance to debug further.